# Listener for IBM MQ

Tags: multithreading, jms, message-queue, ibm-mq

I am trying to create a listener for IBM MQ queue , to read message when its put to the queue using native API.

Is it better to use Thread/TimerTask to perform the GET every second.

I need to use the CCDT , username and password for the authentication purpose.

Is there any default listener available?
Reading from using below code

```
MQMessage theMessage    = new MQMessage();
MQGetMessageOptions mqGetMessageOptions = new MQGetMessageOptions();

mqGetMessageOptions.options=MQC.MQGMO_WAIT | MQC.MQGMO_BROWSE_FIRST;
mqGetMessageOptions.matchOptions=MQC.MQMO_NONE;
mqGetMessageOptions.waitInterval=5000;
try{
        //read the message from queue          
queue.get(theMessage,mqGetMessageOptions);  
  mqGetMessageOptions.options = MQC.MQGMO_MSG_UNDER_CURSOR;

    queue.get(theMessage, mqGetMessageOptions);
```

Comment: What do you say you need to use the CCDT for username and password authentication purpose?  What is authenticating this?  Is this MQ v8 or later native connection authentication or is this some form of security exit on the server side?  One way to authentication to MQ v8 or later is with the mqcred exit, is this why you think you need to use the CCDT?

Comment: Yeah   queueManager = new MQQueueManager(qManager, chanTab); in order to connect to the Queue Manager i pass the CCDT file

Comment: I asked a few difference questions, what does "Yeah" refer to?  Are you confirming the queue manager is using MQ v8 and later Connection authentication?

Comment: Is the CCDT have a CLNTCONN channel using mqcred the mqcred exit?

Comment: I need to pass all the 3 variables , username , password and CCDT file inorder to get the connection. MQ is V8. The CCDT i am using is not having the client side security exit configured. And CHLAUTH rules are configured to control access to  WebSphere MQ queue managers.

Comment: If you are directly passing username and password, then what benefit is the CCDT giving you over directly passing the connection information?

Comment: Yeah , i just realized that.. (CCDT) contains the channel definitions and authentication information right.. If iam setting all of those properties using  com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactory class and getting connection mqQueueConnectionFactory.createConnection( then i dont need CCDT right?

Comment: That is correct, the CCDT does not not include authentication information directly, it only contains the details of how to connect to the queue manager such as channel name, hostname, etc.  It can include a security exit name and in come cases this is used to pass authentication information.  For your existing "listener using an API" you should be able to just add in the passing of authentication without the need for a CCDT.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is browse the messages and not consuming them (big difference).

Second, you should always use the MQC.MQGMO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING option.
i.e.

```
mqGetMessageOptions.options=MQC.MQGMO_WAIT | MQC.MQGMO_BROWSE_FIRST | MQC.MQGMO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING;
```

Third, do not use polling to access a queue - your thread/timer idea.  It is a waste of resources.  You already have a 5 second wait interval defined for the MQGET, if it is not long enough, then increase it to something more reasonable.

Finally, why did you tag this question with 'JMS'.  There is nothing in your question related to JMS.

Comment: We can connect to MQ using JMS as well.. basically i need solution for MQ listner.. I already have a listner using an API but its not accepting CDT file for authentication

Comment: D'oh! Of course not.  CCDT file contains connection information and should NEVER EVER contain UserId and Password.  You set the UsertId and Password in the code. For JMS, it is on the createQueueConnection() method.